# French sci-fi novel about the last man from earth traveling to a different planet and bringing team sports to the natives

Tags: story-identification, novel

I guess the novel starts as the last Earthman travels to different planet, which is populated by primitive humans, the main character introduces several advances and also  team sports to the primitives and goes back into hibernation.

Time passes and the protagonist wakes up and has to rescue the group that he interacted with, as it was conquered by a different group in the meantime. He is successful and also establishes a secret society "the guardians of eternity".

Comment: When did you read this?  Do you recall the cover art?  The name of the planet?

Comment: When you say "back into hibernation" does that mean he hibernated during his trip to the other planet?

Comment: I read the b ook in the Czech translation in the 1990s in the local library, but as i went through it recently, it appears it is no longer there, from the position it was in the author's name should be from the start of the Alphabet, most likely A-G.

Comment: @nebogipfel I think so